# Express a "case ... of" pattern more elegantly in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, fixed-point-iteration

I came across a pattern which I believe can be expressed more elegantly:

I have two functions `f1,f2 :: Int -> Int` (their impl. is not relevant), and a `process :: Int -> Int` which does the following:

- if `f1 x` produces `x1` different from `x`, then repeat the process with `x1`
- otherwise, if `f2 x` produces `x2` different from `x`, then repeat the process with `x2`
- finally, stop the process and return `x`

My `case ... of` implementation is the following:

```hs
f1 :: Int -> Int
f1 = undefined

f2 :: Int -> Int
f2 = undefined

process :: Int -> Int
process x =
    case f1 x of
        x ->
            case f2 x of
                x -> x
                x' -> process x'
        x' -> process x'
```

which produces the following warnings:

```
so.hs:13:17: warning: [-Woverlapping-patterns]
    Pattern match is redundant
    In a case alternative: x' -> ...
   |
13 |                 x' -> process x'
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

so.hs:14:9: warning: [-Woverlapping-patterns]
    Pattern match is redundant
    In a case alternative: x' -> ...
   |
14 |         x' -> process x'
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Can anyone shed some light as to what patterns are overlapping, and how to implement `process` more elegantly?

Comment: `x -> x` will *always* match, since `x` is here seen as a *more local* variable. It will thus not "fire" if it is equal to the value of the outer x, but simply assign `f1 x` to a local variable `x`.

Comment: Right, I see it now. If I understand correctly, It becomes clear when you replace `case <expr> of ...` with a new function pattern matching `<expr>`, the `x`s are different.

Comment: if you compile with `-Wname-shadowing`, the compiler will warn for variable shadowing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to write a pattern for "a value equal to the one I have stored in a variable `x`". This is because pattern matching is the primary way variables are **created** in Haskell.

```
process :: Int -> Int
process x =
```

Here `x` is a pattern. It's a very simple pattern, since it just matches any possible value for the argument to `process`, but you *could* have written a more structured pattern, or even multiple equations for `process` matching different patterns for that argument. And within the scope of that pattern match (the entire RHS of `process`), you have `x` as a local variable referring to the matched value.

```
    case f1 x of
        x ->
```

Here `x` is once again a pattern, and once again it is a very simple pattern matching any possible value that was inspected by the `case` expression. Then you have `x` as a new local variable referring to the matched value within the scope of the match (everything the RHS of the `->` arrow); and because you have created two local variables with the same name `x`, the most local one shadows the other in the scope where they both apply (so you have no way of referring to the original `x` in the RHS of the `->` arrow, only the new `x` that is the result of `f` applied to the original `x`).

If you think the pattern `x` in the case expression ought to mean "match a value equal to `x`", then why should the pattern `x` in the function argument mean "match anything and call it `x`"? You can't have your cake and eat it too<sup>1</sup>.

Haskell makes the rule very simple: a variable appearing in a pattern is *always* the creation of a new variable to refer to the value that matched the pattern. It is *never* a reference to an existing variable to check if the matched value is equal to it. Only constructors will be "checked to see if they match"; variables are just bound to whatever is there<sup>2</sup>.

The same applies to your inner `case`, where you meant to test the result to see if it was still `x` but actually just created yet another `x` shadowing both of the outer `x` variables.

This is why the compiler complains about your other pattern matches being redundant. Pattern are checked in order, and the first pattern in each `case` already matches anything (and calls it `x`), so the second match in each `case` will never even be tried.

So, since pattern matching can *never* test whether a value is equal to a variable, you just need to use a construct other than pattern matching! `if ... then ... else ...` would work fine. You could also use a guard on a pattern.

---

<sup>2</sup> At least not if you want to be able to tell what a pattern means locally, without examining all containing scopes including the entire module and all imports. A hypothetical language *could* decide the meaning of the pattern based on whether there's already a variable of that name in scope, but I think Haskell makes right call here. Unexpected shadowing sometimes causes tricky bugs, but at least some sign of them is always *local*. It would be a nightmare if you could change a pattern from a catch-all to an equality check by introducing a global scope variable with the same name (possibly not even in the same module or even package!).

---

<sup>2</sup> This is actually the core reason we have the syntactic distinction between constructors starting with a capital letter and variables starting with a lowercase letter! The language designers wanted it to be easy to tell at a glance which words are constructors to be matched and which are variables to be bound, without having to consider all the constructor names in scope.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I also wrote a version with guards (see my answer below) which I believe is fine.

Comment: @AlexandruDinu Yeah, the guard version with `/=` is much nicer; I'll remove my code example and let yours stand as the example solution. My answer can just be the explanation. :)

Comment: You *could* express “a value equal to the one I have stored in a variable `x`” using the `ViewPatterns` language option, with the pattern `((== x) -> True)`, but it’s normally not worth doing, since it’s much simpler to write as a guard or `if`.

Comment: @JonPurdy True; `ViewPatterns` allows a form of pattern that is not solely made up of components that are themselves sub-patterns (i.e. `(== x)` is an expression, not a pattern), and in those non-pattern parts you can refer to existing variables rather than bind new ones. I reckon I could plausibly argue a technicality that my generalities about patterns are still true (but only for the pattern parts of patterns), but the truth is I simply forgot `ViewPatterns` were a thing. :)

Comment: @Ben: Oh yeah your answer is morally more correct—I think it’s worth being aware of what you can technically do, but stick to what’s actually done unless you have a particular reason.

Answer (score 5):

Following [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/450128/ben)'s advice, I wrote the following:

```hs
process :: Int -> Int
process x
    | x /= x1 = process x1
    | x /= x2 = process x2
    | otherwise = x
  where
    x1 = f1 x
    x2 = f2 x
```

Comment: there are also patterns with guards, e.g. `process x = let { x1 = f1 x; x2 = f2 x } in case x of { _ | x==x1 -> process x1 ; _ | x==x2 -> process x2 ; _ -> x }`.